# How to connect to a live database with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am currently trying to move my project to a live server but i get the following problem

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I am aware that the script is connecting to the database but it is not giving my access and keeps timing out, i have added the privilege to connect to phpmyadmin.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `xxxxx`.* TO 'Admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Here is my connection information:

```
"Database" => array(
      "host" => "xxx.xx.xx.xxx",
      "username" => "Admin",
      "password" => "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "database" => "xxxxx"
    ),
```

I know the database name is correct as before the error would just say "can not find database hopp2"

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$settings['Database']['host'].';dbname='.$settings['Database']['database'];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn,$settings['Database']['username'],$settings['Database']['password']);
```

Any help would be more than Appreciated, My apologies if this is something simple just desperate as i am on a very tight schedule for this project

```
User name   Host name   Password    Global privileges   User group  Grant   Action
Admin   %   Yes ALL PRIVILEGES      Yes Edit privileges Edit privileges Export Export
```

Comment: it's because default server mysql not allow to access by another server so you have to make your database public access then you can access

Comment: Yea sorry, re-read the question and realised you were not just asking a silly question

Comment: I would say that using an account with All those privilages to get your web site access to the database is incredibly dangerous, but I am assuming you gave it everything in an effort to get something working

Comment: I assume you have double checked the ip address of the MySQL Server. If that were not the one your account was allowed access to, you might get this kind of error

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah saw that comment it's all good i get it happens on here a lot i face palmed a little when i read your comment haha, I added Privilege for all networks to use that account but still have the same issue

Comment: @NishitManjarawala `database public access` please don't advise that. Databases should never be directly connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a firewall issue to me. Have you checked if you can connect with the MySQL server (without using PHP)?:

Try connecting with telnet, to test the connection:

```
telnet IP 3306
```

You should at least get a connection (without logging in). If this does not work, try to find out whether the server accepts a connection at 3306, but fails to respond, this means that outgoing traffic is being blocked.

Comment: Yeah just tried tracert on windows routed there fine, The Server is just a Digital Ocean server so i added all firewalls correct

Comment: But still having the same issues

Comment: Sorry should add that the DigitalOcean server is a One-click phpmyadmin droplet

Comment: And if you tracert from the droplet itself?

Comment: Still the same result, Still haven't found the problem I will just not make the Database live to the internet, I was only doing it that way so if the system went down the database could still be intact and I could just load a backup copy of the website onto the database instantly. But it is taking too much time soi have moved on